# Open a specific file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filepath

I want my program to open a specific .txt file. The text file will always stay in the same folder within the solution folder. However, the location of the solution folder itself may change if the solution is moved to a different computer, or a different directory on the current computer.

I know how to hardcode the file path append the file name and then open it. But how can I define the file path so that the file can still be opened if the solution moves to a different computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to say your FileName.txt was always present in the same directory as the assembly, you could do something simple like this:

```
Function GetAssemblyDirectoryPath() As String
    Dim fullAssemblyPath As String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
    Return fullAssemblyPath.Substring(0, fullAssemblyPath.LastIndexOf("\"c))
End Function
```

This just returns the path to the folder where the assembly resides.  The "Solution" might not always be present, but the assembly will, so this will work in both cases (if you make sure the file is always copied to the output directory).

Comment: This does not just return the file path. It returns filepath\Projectname.exe, so I can not just append my file name to this. I could do something messy like take the last n characters off this string, but that seems like a bad option.

Comment: Not that's not correct.  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location returns the filepath\Projectname.exe, but if you use the whole function I posted, it strips out the file name and just gives you the folder path.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is contained within the solution, you can use a virtual path which is then mapped to a physical path using `Server.MapPath`

The following should work :

```
Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/FileName.txt")
```

Please note that the location of FileName.txt in my example is in the root of the solution and not in any specified folders, `~/` is essentially the root of the current solution.

For more information on the Server.MapPath method and Virtual Paths see below:

[Server.MapPath MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Virtual Path Utility Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx)

Comment: Does not work. Error "Name 'server' is not declared". No correction suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your application (.exe) and (.txt) files are in the same folder, then just use the file name - do not put the path.

```
IO.File.OpenText("thefile.txt")
```

Edited:
Mostly "current working directory" is the same directory where the (.exe) file exists. Yes, sometimes, it is not the same directory. Thus, Application.ExecutablePath would be the right solution.

```
Dim fn As String
fn = Application.ExecutablePath.Remove(Application.ExecutablePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1) & "thefile.txt"
IO.File.OpenText("thefile.txt")
```

...

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is necessarily true.  According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx, it assumes the "current working directory" when using a relative path.  And according to the definition of that (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx), it's not always the same as the directory the process was started from.

Comment: @roryap you have pointed out the good point. Mostly "current working directory" is the same directory where the (.exe) file exists. Yes, sometimes, it is not the same directory. Thus, `Application.ExecutablePath` would be the right solution. Thanks

Comment: This does not work either, it gives an error "Executable is not a member of system.windows.forms.application".

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about a desktop application,   application.ExecutablePath will do what you want. It's not really a good idea though, if your application will reside within Program Files - it's best to avoid writing to anywhere within there, and you will have to run as administrator on post-XP OS's .